# Problem with sorting objects

Tags: linq, sorting, c#-4.0

I have a collection of `Car`:

```
var cars = new List<Car>();
cars.Add(new Car { ProductionDate = new DateTime(2011,02,02) });
cars.Add(new Car { ProductionDate = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01) });
cars.Add(new Car { ProductionDate = new DateTime(2011,04,04,04,04,04) });
cars.Add(new Car { ProductionDate = new DateTime(2011, 03, 03, 3, 3, 3) });
```

I need to sort it by `ProductionDate`.

Result should be that at first I will have cars with date with time, so it should be car with 2011, 03, 03, 3, 3, 3 as production date, and at the end should be car with 2011, 02, 02 as production date. Second should be car with 2011, 04, 04, 04, 04, 04, and the third with 2011, 02, 02.

I can do it by using `foreach` but I believe that there is nicer way to do it.

Comment: And if a car is built at 0:00? A DateTime is made of a Data+Time. You can't see if the Time part is missing!

Comment: I didn't add it, but if date is 0:00 I will regard it as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cars.Sort((p, q) => {
    var tm1 = p.ProductionDate.TimeOfDay;
    var tm2 = q.ProductionDate.TimeOfDay;

    if (tm1.Ticks == 0) {
        if (tm2.Ticks == 0) {
            return p.ProductionDate.CompareTo(q.ProductionDate);
        }
        return 1;
    } else if (tm2.Ticks == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return p.ProductionDate.CompareTo(q.ProductionDate);
    }
});
```

But remember: what happens if a car is built at 0:00? A DateTime is made of a Data+Time. You can't see if the Time part is missing!

I'll add that if you need to use the `Enumerable.OrderBy`, then you can use my lamdba function with the `LambdaComparer` that you can find around the internet (as suggested by sll)

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan zeroTime = new TimeSpan(0);
var sortedCars = cars.OrderBy(c => c.ProductionDate.TimeOfDay.Equals(zeroTime) ? 1 : 0)
                     .ThenBy(c => c.ProductionDate)
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like that

```
    var carsWithoutProductionTime = from car in cars
                                    where car.ProductionDate.Hour == 0
                                    orderby car.ProductionDate
                                    select car;

    var carsWithProductionTime = from car in cars
                                 where car.ProductionDate.Hour != 0
                                 orderby car.ProductionDate
                                 select car;

    var mergedCars = carsWithProductionTime.Union(carsWithoutProductionTime);
```

but It looks ugly. I would like to see something more sophisticated :)